# web project option in visual studio is not availablle

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

Hi I am new to Visual Studio. 
For staring a new Web project, as all tutorials say, I have to click "New Project" option and then select "Web". but I can't find any option related to web. [Available Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLA8y.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Navigate to below there you will find options for your website.
File -> New-> Website

Comment: Stackoverflow is itself a great tutorial :) up vote it if it worked for you.